# How can the miner access the host like stratum+tcp:// directly

Tags: python, protocols, bitcoin

I found many resources about the Getwork in Bitcoin or Litecoin. It needs me to run a proxy on my computer so that the miner software can get work from the mining pool.

I was wondering how can one access a host like `stratum+tcp://` directly?

Is there any protocol or example code that you know - preferably in 'C' or Python?

Answer (score -1):

no directly but fun. test >> [miningcore](https://github.com/coinfoundry/miningcore) >> to make you stratum...

Comment: Can you give a code example, how this can be achieved?